# Rails - two forms in one (ShopifyAPI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, shopify

Part of the app i'm developing involves a form which has to create a product on the users shopify store and also create a row in my own database for an identical product (with a few extra bits of information).

Where i'm struggling is with the form itself, i can do this with a html based form, but i can't get a single ruby form to do both jobs. A shortened version of my controller create code is as follows;

```
def create
    @item = Item.new
    @item.item_title = params[:item_title]
    @item.item_profit = params[:item_profit]
    @new_product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
    @new_product.title = params[:item_title]
    @new_product.save
    @item.save
end
```

So as you can see i'm using the same params to set values for both the shopify product and the product in my own db. The HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="/items/submit" >
  <input type="text" name="item_title">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="item_profit">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And it works fine, but how do i convert this into a ruby form that does the same job?

Comment: This is just a normal form, not two forms in one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
form_tag('/items/submit')
  text_field_tag 'item_title'
  tag("br")
  text_field_tag 'item_profit'
  tag("br")
  tag("br")
<%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
```

Instead of tag("br"), you can directly use < br />.

Comment: Accepting answer. Totally forgot about form_tag and was leaning towards form_for hence why i couldn't figure this out